# Turtle has red blood bubble in his tail

Tags: diseases, turtles

My turtle is suffering from same cause which is red blood bubble in his tail which is sacred me thereof. I am living in India where there is no vet facility so please advise me about home remedies which I can do this to my turtle!

**Warning** - Graphic images:

> [image]
>  [image]

Comment: Which breed is it is it Indian star? If yes kindly consult a vet immediately as it might be serious issues

Comment: This looks pretty serious to me so I think it's unlikely that you'll be able to resolve this yourself in your home. I could be wrong and I know you said you can't get to a vet but that would seem the most appropriate action here.

Comment: Go to a vet, immediately

Comment: I tried to find (anything) online that was similar -- no luck. Please share any information from your Veteranarian.

Comment: Let me know where do you leave in India there are good vets in India also.